# Vectorize add-subtract loop in NumPy using O(1) space?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, vectorization

It's easy to vectorize this code with NumPy using extra buffers:

```
import numpy.random

def foo(a, b):
    for k in xrange(n):
        bk = b[k]
        b[k] = a[k] - bk
        a[k] += bk

n = 16
x = numpy.random.randn(n)  # some arbitrary input array, this is just for example
y = numpy.random.randn(n)  # some arbitrary input array, this is just for example
foo(x, y)
```

But is there any way for me to make NumPy do so **without** allocating extra arrays/buffers?

#### Edit:

I was intending this do this in only 1 vectorized operation (so that each memory location is written to only once), sorry for not mentioning that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
a += b
b *= -2
b += a
```

Comment: You're cheating but it's almost right! I think you meant `e += o; o *= 2; o = numpy.subtract(e, o, o)`. That said, I was hoping to do this in 1 vectorized operation, not 3, sorry... is there any way to do that?

Comment: Cheating, eh ;-) Just for the record I wouldn't call this a factor of 3, more like 1.5. `a` is assigned once, `b` is assigned twice. -- I can't think of a way that is shorter and vectorised. Let's see what others come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do the trick?

```
import numpy.random

def foo(a, b):
    for k in xrange(n):
        a[k], b[k] = (a[k] + b[k], a[k] - b[k])

n = 16
x = numpy.random.randn(n)  # some arbitrary input array, this is just for example
y = numpy.random.randn(n)  # some arbitrary input array, this is just for example
foo(x, y)
```

I don't think it's possible to do what you want in a single vectorized operation because assigning values to multiple variables can't be done at once... But I think cheating with a tuple makes it look like it's possible :]

Answer (score 0):

Vectorization essentially means performing loops in compiled code rather than in the high level language. Numpy has many such functions written in C, but I don't think there is one for this particular case... So, roll your own - if you can use Cython on your platform this is straight-forward:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def c_foo(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] a, np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] b):
    cdef int n = a.shape[0]
    cdef int k
    cdef float bk
    for k in range(n):  # not sure if Cython likes `range` or `xrange` better on Python 2
        bk = b[k]
        b[k] = a[k] - bk
        a[k] += bk
```

<sub>(I did not check if this works due to lacking a compiler on my system, but Cython correctly created a .c file from this code.)</sub>

This looks like an operation that may be commonly used in audio processing to separate a stereo signal in two mono/diff signals. You may be lucky and find an existing implementation in scipy or in an audio processing library.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that only works if we control the memory layout. Specifically, `x` and `y` must be interleaved and `float`:

```
xy = np.random.randn(4, 2)
x, y = xy.T
print(x, y)
print(x-y, x+y)
xyc = xy.view(np.complex)
xyc *= 1+1j
print(x, y)
```

Sample output:

```
[ 1.17611837 -0.51923153 -0.35347014  0.17090538] [ 0.76679875  0.49908488  0.55649176  1.01126514]
[ 0.40931962 -1.0183164  -0.9099619  -0.84035975] [ 1.94291712 -0.02014665  0.20302162  1.18217052]
[ 0.40931962 -1.0183164  -0.9099619  -0.84035975] [ 1.94291712 -0.02014665  0.20302162  1.18217052]
```